Corner plot in log scale
I am using the corner library to make a corner plot. However, when I set the axes_scale parameter to log, nothing changes. I know that I can put everything in log scale before plotting, but I would prefer to do it inside corner.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import corner

# Generate data
n_samples = 10000
n_parameters = 3
samples = np.random.randn(n_samples, n_parameters)


# Generate the corner plot
fig = corner.corner(samples, 
                    axes_scale=['log','linear','log'],
                    show_titles=True)

plt.show()

Nothing changes even with axes_scale='log'.
Any help is appreciated.


An example where axes_scale works
The following snippet produces a corner with log-scaled axes:

import numpy as np
import corner
import arviz as az

# Generate data
n_samples = 10000
samples = az.from_dict({
    "log_a": np.random.lognormal(0, 1, n_samples),
    "linear_b": np.random.normal(0, 1, n_samples),
    "log_c": np.random.lognormal(0, 1, n_samples),
})

corner.corner(
    samples,
    axes_scale=['log', 'linear', 'log'],
    show_titles=True
).savefig("corner_plot.png")




Why @alessandro-peca 's example does not yield log-scales
The samples are negative in @alessandro-peca's example, leading to nans bins.
Using corner==2.2.2, @alessandro-peca's example yields the following error:
ValueError: It looks like at least one of your sample columns have no dynamic range. 
You could try using the 'range' argument.

This is how the bins are created:
https://github.com/dfm/corner.py/blob/2f2152bd2804ac4d4c7cee2c762cef3740bf4318/src/corner/core.py#L222
bins_1d = np.logspace(
      np.log10(min(range[i])), np.log10(max(range[i])), n_bins_1d + 1
)

The lower bin will be a nan.
Also see the GH issue :)

Your code is incomplete. But I guess this'd be what you're aiming for:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import corner

n_samples = 10000
n_parameters = 3
samples = np.random.randn(n_samples, n_parameters)


lgs = samples.copy()
lgs[:, 0] = np.log10(lgs[:, 0] - np.min(lgs[:, 0]) + 1)
lgs[:, 2] = np.log10(lgs[:, 2] - np.min(lgs[:, 2]) + 1)

fig = corner.corner(samples,
                    show_titles=True,
                    labels=['log', 'linear', 'log'])

plt.show()



Prints


Just updated with a plot. You are changing the labels, while I want to change the ax scale

@AlessandroPeca I think that axes_scale is depreciated. Check the documentations.

@AlessandroPeca Manually change it?

I see. But I would need something automated.

@AlessandroPeca Hold on a bit, maybe someone may have a better answer.

As of corner v2.2.2, axes_scale is still present and not depreciated. Docs.
